Problem Decoding MP3 to PCM with Noise Artifacts on NXP RT1062
I am working on a firmware for the NXP RT1062 where I am successfully playing audio in PCM format. I wanted to add MP3 decoding functionality. To achieve this, I did the following:

Left the PCM playback and data-fetching layers untouched (audio is
fetched over the internet).
Added an intermediate layer for MP3
decoding.
The decoded PCM is written to the same buffer used for
playback, which works perfectly for PCM in the current version.

The issue arises with MP3 data from ElevenLabs (22050Hz, 32kbps, mono). The audio plays, but with interleaved noise. The noise appears as a periodic pulse train at ~20Hz, where part of the cycle has proper audio and the other part is noisy.
This is not likely caused by:

Channel interleaving: 20Hz is far too slow for this, and channels
would interleave every 2 bytes.
Buffer accumulation/delay: I’ve observed occasional delays (every ~10 seconds), but that’s unrelated and much larger than the periodic noise.

I am using lieff/minimp3 with the following flags:

MINIMP3_ONLY_MP3
MINIMP3_NONSTANDARD_BUT_LOGICAL
HAVE_ARMV6 (automatically enabled based on build conditions)

Additional Context

I use external RAM, which has limitations (can only start writing at even addresses). However, I tested with on-chip RAM, and
the issue persists.
The MP3 file is detected, parsed, and partially
decoded, as frameInfo variable is filled correctly and I can hear coherent audio mixed with the noise. The
playback works fine for other PCM sources in the same version of the program, so the issue seems
isolated to MP3 decoding.

This is my main MP3 parsing function:
size_t MainApp::parseMP3(char *audioBuffer, size_t bufferSize) {
    mp3dec_t mp3Decoder;
    mp3dec_frame_info_t frameInfo;
    mp3dec_init(&mp3Decoder);
    size_t offset = MP3_FRAME_PADDING - mp3LeftoverSize;

    if (mp3LeftoverSize > 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mp3LeftoverSize; i += 2) {
            memcpy(audioBuffer + offset + i, &(mp3LeftoverBuffer[i * 2]), 2);
        }
    }

    size_t completeFramesSize = 0;
    size_t frameCount = 0;
    findLastMP3Frame(audioBuffer + offset, bufferSize + mp3LeftoverSize, &completeFramesSize, &frameCount);
    PRINTF("%d complete frames found\r\n", frameCount);
    size_t totalSamplesDecoded = 0;
    size_t pcmPointer = 0;
    size_t mp3Pointer = 0;

    while (mp3Pointer < completeFramesSize) {
        size_t toRead = completeFramesSize - mp3Pointer;

        size_t samplesDecoded = mp3dec_decode_frame(&mp3Decoder,
            (const uint8_t*) audioBuffer + offset + mp3Pointer, toRead,
            (mp3d_sample_t*) pcmAudioBuffer + pcmPointer, &frameInfo);
        mp3Pointer += frameInfo.frame_bytes;

        if (frameInfo.frame_bytes == 0) {
            PRINTF("Insufficient data %d ", completeFramesSize - mp3Pointer);
            break;
        }

        totalSamplesDecoded += samplesDecoded;
        pcmPointer += samplesDecoded * 2;
    }

    mp3LeftoverSize = bufferSize + mp3LeftoverSize - completeFramesSize;
    if (mp3LeftoverSize > 0) {
        memcpy(mp3LeftoverBuffer, audioBuffer + offset + completeFramesSize, mp3LeftoverSize);
    }

    PRINTF("%d bytes of complete frames decoded, %d remaining\r\n", completeFramesSize, mp3LeftoverSize);
    PRINTF("%d bytes of PCM data\r\n", totalSamplesDecoded * 2);
    return totalSamplesDecoded * 2;
}



